# Django - queries across relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django and I am trying to implement this Relationship in Django

> > Person has a Car
> >     Car can be tested for problems
> >     A car should be tested for a select set of criterias

So I implement it as

```
class Person(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    license = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    isDiesel = models.BooleanField()
```

I am trying to import the fields of car into test. Is there anyway way to do it? 
I am trying to replicate this SQL statement

```
 SELECT test FROM table WHERE OWNER IS x (object instance) AND CAR IS isDiesel
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Car.objects.filter(isDiesel=True, owner=person_instance)
```

This will return an array of `Car` objects.

You should have a read [at the Django docs on this subject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/); this framework has a really badass documentation.

Comment: I forgot mention
`class Test(models.Model)` is a class within which I am expected to define this. Would this solution work within that?